# Sharing config parameter among servlets

Tags: java, servlets

Is there a way two (or more) servlets can share config parameter, declared once in `web.xml`?

Looked [here](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.EnvEntry), but it doesn't seem to be the answer.

The use-case is fairly simple: I have two servlets: one uploads files to a directory, other downloads them. I would be happy to enlist the directory/path only once in `web.xml` to avoid ambiguity/confusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, add a `<context-param>` to your `web.xml`, e.g.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>myParam</param-name>
   <param-value>Some value</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This is scoped to the webapp as a whole, rather than individual servlets.

You can then obtain this in your servlet(s) from the `getInitParameter(...)` method of the `ServletContext` object (which in turn can be obtained using `getServletContext()` in your servlet).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could declare an `<env-entry>` in your `web.xml`:

```
  <env-entry>
    <description>This is the address of the SMTP host that shall be used to send mails
    </description>
    <env-entry-name>smtp.mailhost</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>mailhost</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

The value can then be looked up using JNDI and can be set at deploy time (how this is done is container-specific) without modifying the WAR/EAR file. The `<env-entry-value>` serves as a default if no deply-time value has been set - it can also be omitted if no meaningful default is available for a particular setting.